# Unable to write data to delta table for the first time to specifed location eventhought using .format("delta")

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I am trying to write the data to delta table sink(ADLS Gen2 mounted to databricks) and I am getting the below error, Please note that I am writing the data for the first time to the delta table and no table/folder was created manually for that sink

```
AnalysisException: 'Incompatible format detected.\n\nYou are trying to write to `dbfs:/mnt/delta/path/` using Databricks Delta, but there is no\ntransaction log present. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing\using format("delta") and that you are trying to write to the table base path.\n\nTo disable this check, SET spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled=false\nTo learn more about Delta, see https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/delta/index.html\n
```

I am using below code:

```
df.writeStream \
      .format("delta")\
      .trigger(once=True)\
      .foreachBatch(forEachFunc) \
      .option("checkpointLocation", "%s/_checkpoint" % vDeltaTablePath) \
      .start()
```

But when I set the below configuration, my pyspark application was able to write the data to sink

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled", False)
```

or when i create the delta table manually (and without setting the above mentioned configuration) and then if I write the data to the specified sink my pyspark application was able to write the data to delta table sink without errors

```
delta_table = f"""CREATE TABLE `delta`.`/mnt/{datalake}/delta/path`(
  id INT,
  name STRING
  )
  USING delta
  """
  spark.sql(delta_table)
```

So my question here is, is it ok to set the above mentioned spark configuration instead of creating delta table manually in a production environment

Another Question:
Also is it ok to enable rocks_db configuration in databricks when my pyspark application is doing operations like stack and join(I am suing broadcast join). I hope these two are stateful operations.

```
spark.conf.set(
        "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass",
        "com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider",
    )
```

For each function, I am using,

```
def forEachFunc(df, batch_id):
  if vLoad == "Delta":
    df1 = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, vPath)
    df1.alias("tgt") \
    .merge(df.alias("src"), \
          "(tgt.id = src.id) and (tgt.id1 = src.id1) and (tgt.timestamp = src.timestamp)") \
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
    .execute()
  elif vLoad == "Init":
    dfLoad.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(vPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `foreachBatch(forEachFunc)`, `format("delta")` is not used.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! But in another application I am not using foreachBatch (except that everything I mentioned in the code is the same) and I am still getting Incompatible format detected error(which I mentioned in the question) when I am  not setting spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled", False) or creating the delta table manually with the expected schema from the streaming data frame

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse, Even without using forEachFunc, I am getting the s[ecified error. Added the forEachFunc i am using in the question

Comment: Can you `%fs ls dbfs:/mnt/delta/path`? I suspect that the directory was created mistakenly for a non-delta table and hence the issue. The exception says it all: _"no transaction log"_ (i.e. `_delta_log`).